# Bash script to zip all the files that begin the same characters

Tags: bash, zip, file-management

I have a folder where files are being constantly added from other users. I would like to use a bash script to compare the first three characters in a filename of these files and if they are the same zip them together.

I'm a newbie to bash (or any) scripting so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `I'm a newbie to bash ...` -- and you want to maintain *status quo*!

Answer (score 0):

The key part is the `find` command. It only selects files in current directory with a match in first three characters of the last part of the path (filename):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '.*/fil.*' -print
```

And now simply provide that output to your favorite compression tool:

For a `bzip2` file using `tar`:

```
tar -cjf myfile.tbz2 $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '.*/fil.*' -print)
```

For a `zip` file using `7z`:

```
7z a myfile.zip $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '.*/fil.*' -print)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a technique to find the unique 3-character prefixes

```
command ls | grep -o '^.\{1,3\}' | sort -u
```

Be careful with files with names less than 3 characters.

This does not restrict the list to files, nor does it pick up hidden files.